# how to call class properties in function with Python

Tags: python, class

Here is an example:

I have a student class like this

```
class student():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.name = x
        self.age = y
        self.ID = z
```

and a function to print the corresponding property:

```
def printer(student, parameter_name):
    print(student.parameter_name)
```

My goal is to print the property I want via the function:

```
s1 = student('John', '14', '9927')

printer(s1, age)
14

print(s1, name)
John
```

But, actually, my function raises an error: "AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'parameter_name'"

So, how to fix the error and complete my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `parameter_name` is a ***string***, not a property of the student object. To fix this error, you need to use the `getattr` function to ***dynamically*** access the desired property:

```
def printer(student, parameter_name):
    print(getattr(student, parameter_name))
```

With this change, the following code should work as expected:

```
s1 = student('John', '14', '9927')

printer(s1, 'age')
14

print(s1, 'name')
John
```